# Struts2 There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [order problem in include file]

Tags: java, struts2

If I include 2 or more files in my struts config file, only the first file works, not second one. If I swap the order, putting the second file as the first file then it starts working, which means that whatever is in the first position works, and that's it. How can I get it to work?

`<include file="../configuration/struts/struts_1.xml"></include>
<include file="../configuration/struts/struts_2.xml"></include>`

Comment: it is not in the jsp file iam saying about struts.xml file

Comment: how to include multiple struts comfiguration files in struts.xml file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826586/573032

Comment: iam usign default pacakge in every struts file. so is it the reason that's why second file is not including..

Comment: It's used every time in the configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624655/573032